# How to mount a VM disk to another VM without deleting the original VM?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, azure

Context - Azure, **Resource Manager**. Have 2 VM.

first - broken VM, some file be corrupted.

second - new VM.

On first VM static IP, so we can't just delete it and mount drive to second VM.

Is there a way to mount a disk from first to second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can only mount a disk on 1 VM at a time. Why not move the IP to the new VM?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. You can download a copy of the VHD and mount that for inspection though. But you cannot mount the same VHD to multiple VMs.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to mount a disk from first to second?

In brief, no. You need to delete the VM and recreate it after fix.

> On first VM static IP, so we can't just delete it and mount drive to second VM.

It's by design. If your second VM is using the dynamic public IP address, then you can not change it to a static public IP. But you can reuse the static public IP when you recreate your VM.

To recreate a VM with same VHD file in ARM, please follow this [guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd).

If you want to use your original public IP, then you can use the command below when you create the new VM:

**$pip = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name** *your_public_ip_name* **-ResourceGroupName** *resource_group_name*